# Upgrading to android marshmallow 6.0.1 unable to connect ADB in android studio 2.2

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

After upgrading to marshmallow 6.0.1 . When I go to run the application, my device no longer show in android studio chooser option. In my phone Developer option is enable and USB configuration is set to MTP. When i connect my phone to PC via usb cable it doesn't show on the PC as well as my phone also doesn't show notification to change usb configuration charging to mtp or etc. But after connecting my to PC via cable it starts charging. I have Samsung J7 16. Also i attached a different phone OPPO it shows same as my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the driver of your device on your computer. You can find it on the Internet. Some phones need drivers installed on computer.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#RealDevice) and install driver match with your device from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ADB has problem. Try to run in the console (AndroidStudio or your system), with the phone connected:

```
adb usb
```

Now ADB should restart in usb mode. Then check on the smartphone, on top notification, if it is connected as usb storage or just in charging mode.
If this doesn't work, try to clean the fingerprint between the pc and the phone, on **smartphone>general>developer options> revoke authorization debug USB** (or somehing similar). Try to sconnect/connect the phone again, a popup should ask you if you want to enable the pc for developing

Comment: i already used that revoke authorization debug USB to clear all authorization. but nothing happened. ADB works correctly on lower android versions like 5.0

Comment: Is the smartphone connected in the right way? When you connect it to the pc, is there a notification that pops up asking you in which way you want to connect the smartphone? ..otherwise simply there isn't a good connection, try to change cable or try to connect to the smartphone with adb by tcp/ip